# Java Lambda not reading Records from Kinesis Events

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-kinesis

I am trying to read events from Kinesis Data Stream to Lambda written in both Java and Python. The Events are being pushed to Kinesis from DMS and finally read in Java.

Here is my java code

```
public class RequestEventHandler implements RequestHandler<KinesisEvent, Void> {

  @Override
  public Void handleRequest(KinesisEvent kinesisEvent, Context context) {
    System.out.println("kinesis handler called");
    System.out.println("kinesisEvent::: " + kinesisEvent);
    System.out.println("kinesisContext::: " + context);
    for (KinesisEvent.KinesisEventRecord record : kinesisEvent.getRecords()) {
      System.out.println("KinesisEventRecord:::" + record);
      System.out.println("KinesisRecord:::" + record.getKinesis());
      /* String data  = new String(Base64.decode(record.getKinesis().getData().array()));
      System.out.println("data from kinesis record " + data);*/
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```

The dependencies added are in pom.xml is

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
  <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-core</artifactId>
  <version>1.11.619</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
  <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-events</artifactId>
  <version>1.11.619</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
  <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-kinesis</artifactId>
  <version>1.11.619</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
  <artifactId>aws-lambda-java-core</artifactId>
  <version>1.1.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
  <artifactId>aws-lambda-java-events</artifactId>
  <version>1.3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Here is my Python code

```
from __future__ import print_function
import json
import base64
import time
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    print("Hello world Trigger")
    print("event:", event)
    for record in event['Records']:
       #print(record)
       #Kinesis data is base64 encoded so decode here
       print(record["kinesis"]["data"])
       payload=base64.b64decode(record["kinesis"]["data"])
       print("Decoded payload: " + str(payload))
    print("Lambda function ARN:", context.invoked_function_arn)
    print("CloudWatch log stream name:", context.log_stream_name)
    print("CloudWatch log group name:",  context.log_group_name)
    print("Lambda Request ID:", context.aws_request_id)
    print("Lambda function memory limits in MB:", context.memory_limit_in_mb)
    # We have added a 1 second delay so you can see the time remaining in get_remaining_time_in_millis.
    time.sleep(1) 
    print("Lambda time remaining in MS:", context.get_remaining_time_in_millis())
```

What we are noticing is for the same event which looks something like this

```
{
  "Records": [
    {
      "kinesis": {
        "partitionKey": "partitionKey-03",
        "kinesisSchemaVersion": "1.0",
        "data": "SGVsbG8sIHRoaXMgaXMgYSB0ZXN0IDEyMy4=",
        "sequenceNumber": "49545115243490985018280067714973144582180062593244200961",
        "approximateArrivalTimestamp": 1428537600
      },
      "eventSource": "aws:kinesis",
      "eventID": "shardId-000000000000:49545115243490985018280067714973144582180062593244200961",
      "invokeIdentityArn": "arn:aws:iam::EXAMPLE",
      "eventVersion": "1.0",
      "eventName": "aws:kinesis:record",
      "eventSourceARN": "arn:aws:kinesis:EXAMPLE",
      "awsRegion": "us-east-1"
    }
  ]
}
```

The Python code is able to retrieve Records and Data from the event, but the java handler is not able to parse Records and kinesisEvent.getRecords() always comes as null, the java code logs it as

```
kinesis handler called
kinesisEvent::: {[{eventSource: aws:kinesis,kinesis: {SequenceNumber: 49545115243490985018280067714973144582180062593244200961,ApproximateArrivalTimestamp: Thu Apr 09 00:00:00 UTC 2015,Data: java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=26 cap=26],PartitionKey: partitionKey-03,KinesisSchemaVersion: 1.0},eventId: shardId-000000000000:49545115243490985018280067714973144582180062593244200961,invokeIdentityArn: arn:aws:iam::EXAMPLE,eventName: aws:kinesis:record,eventSourceARN: arn:aws:kinesis:EXAMPLE,eventSourceARN: arn:aws:kinesis:EXAMPLE,awsRegion: us-east-1}]}
```

you will notice there is no records in the kinesisEvent, i tried with multiple versions of the aws-lambda-java-events but the same problem. What may be the issue behind this

Comment: So you're getting a `NullPointerException` when you call `kinesisEvent.getRecords()`?